# MongooseError: Cannot read property 'options' of undefined when setting reference

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate

Trying to set a simple reference field in Mongoose is giving me huge problems.
I get the following error. As far as I can tell there are no actual validation errors.

```
'contents.0.modules.0.matches.0.':
      { MongooseError: Cannot read property 'options' of undefined
          at ValidatorError (C:\Users\Simon\Documents\Projects\eventvods\node_modules\mongoose\lib\error\validator.js:24:11)
          at _init (C:\Users\Simon\Documents\Projects\eventvods\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:372:37)
          ...
          at init (C:\Users\Simon\Documents\Projects\eventvods\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:348:7)
          at model.Document.init (C:\Users\Simon\Documents\Projects\eventvods\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:313:3)
        message: 'Cannot read property \'options\' of undefined',
        name: 'ValidatorError',
        properties: [Object],
        kind: 'cast',
        path: undefined,
        value: undefined } } }
```

Mongoose schema like so

```
var matchSchema = new Schema({

    team1: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Teams'
    },
    team2: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Teams'
    },
    team1_2: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Teams'
    },
    team2_2: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Teams'
    },
    ...
});
var moduleSchema = new Schema({
    matches: [matchSchema],
    ...
});
var sectionSchema = new Schema({
    modules: [moduleSchema],
    ...
});
```

A sample object that fails to save:

```
{ 
  team1: 5835a5f653d4ce23bb33ab19,
  team2: 5835a70353d4ce23bb33ab21
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this was a weird one, but I was able to bypass it with a little awkward manipulation.

1. Creating a new schema field of the same type, and setting that to
   the value.
2. Going through all my documents, and setting the
   original field to that field's value.

Answer (score 0):

this is your `team1` definition:

```
team1: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Teams'
}
```

and this is your data in mongo:

```
team1: 5835a5f653d4ce23bb33ab19
```

As you can see, team1 object type is not ObjectId! it's just a normal String!

Mongo stores a reference like this:

```
team1: {
    "$ref" : "Teams",
    "$id" : ObjectId("5835a5f653d4ce23bb33ab19")
}
```

So either fix your data in mongo or fix your scheme!

Comment: I'm afraid you're actually wrong. Passing in `mongoose.mongo.ObjectId(id)` to convert it to an id doesn't work, and I'm also setting references in that exact method elsewhere - which works perfectly fine. It's only these two variables that don't work.

Answer (score -1):

You have not defined your schema correctly. It should be more like so:

```
var matchSchema = new Schema({

team1: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: String
},
team2: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: String
},
team1_2: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: String
},
team2_2: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: String
},
...
});
```